# Faking IO Streams

Tags: c#

As part of my student group's hobby project, I'm creating a simulation of a wired network of microcontrollers in order to test the algorithms we've written. Each controller is wired up to several data ports, which each have an input and output stream. I'm modeling this relationship by giving each port a `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`, each backed by its own `MemoryStream`. However, I ran into a snag when trying to 'connect' ports between different controllers. Simulating the latency is outside the scope of this iteration of the simulation, so I just needed to link them directly somehow.

So my question is this: how can I fake an IO stream like this using two different `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` or `MemoryStream` sets, such that when I write to one the other can immediately read it?

Comment: Are all of the controllers in the same process?  And have you tried anything so far?

Comment: It's all running in the same process and same thread, yes. I've tried directly assigning the input streams to the output streams (`port1.InputStream = port2.OutputStream; port2.InputStream = Port1.OutputStream;`) and recreating the BinaryReaders (`port1.Input = new BinaryReader(port2.Output.BaseStream); port2.Input = new BinaryReader(port1.Output.BaseStream);`). Looking at this again I suppose I could use actual sockets and just connect to localhost, but that's still a bit much for this stage of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using UDP sockets connected to each other via the loopback address, which simulated the asynchronous nature of the network well without dealing with latency issues.

I'm not allowed to publish the actual code, but the implementation was fairly straightforward. Each data port has its own `UdpClient` from the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace and a randomly assigned UDP port. An update loop iterates over each port and calls the `udpClient.Send()` and `udpClient.Receive()` functions as appropriate, using a simple `byte[]` buffer to handle incomplete messages. I think an overview of high-level networking in .Net is outside the scope of this question, but there's some nice resources available on MSDN just a Google search away.

Comment: If you show us your code for “using UDP sockets” I will upvote your answer.